# Data Extension used for Dynamic Content in Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dynamic-content

I have a simple email with a few Dynamic Content Blocks all of them based on the  Data Extension 'A'.

In a Journey, the entry source is the Data Extension 'B' (same structure, same fields than the Data Extension 'A') and the email includes the dynamic content blocks based on the Data Extension 'A'.

I would like to confirm that when the journey is activated, the Dynamic Content blocks of the email will still use the information of Data Extension 'A' instead of 'B'.

If yes, is there a way to change the source of the blocks without having to replicate all of them from scratch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dynamic content blocks will always look at the sendable data extension, to which the email is sent to. So using it in a journey, will use values from the journey data extension - B.

If you want to use logic based on data extension A, you need to replicate the logic behind the dynamic content in AmpScript, using [LookupRows](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookuprows.htm), and *IF/ELSEIF* logic:

```
%%[
SET @Arows = LookupRows('A','SubKey',_subscriberkey)
SET @RowFromA = row(@Arows,1)
SET @PreferenceFromA = field(@RowFromA,"Preference")
IF @PreferenceFromA == "cars" THEN
ContentBlockbyKey("Option1")
ELSEIF @PreferenceFromA == "boats" THEN
ContentBlockbyKey("Option2")
ELSEIF @PreferenceFromA == "motorcycles" THEN
ContentBlockbyKey("Option3")
ELSE
ContentBlockbyKey("DefaultOption")
ENDIF
]%%
```

Answer (score 3):

The Data Extension that's being used for Dynamic Content is the one that you are sending too. So Dynamic Content will be based on Data Extension B, or well, Journey Data. More about Journey Data here.
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_journey_contact_data.htm&type=5

If you want to do personalization based on Data Extension A, then you need to use Lookup functionality in AMPSCript.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookup.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookuporderedrows.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookuprows.htm